# How to parse JSON from an rtf file

Tags: ios, json, swift

Here is my Json.rtf file with the following JSON

```
1.  [
2.      {
3.          “key1”: “value1”,
4.          “key2”: “value2”,
5.          “key3”: “value3”,
6.          “key4”: “value4”
7.      
8.      },
9.      {
10.         “key1”: “value1”,
11.         “key2”: “value2”,
12.         “key3”: “value3”,
13.         “key4”: “value4”
14.     }
15. ]
```

Here is the code i tried

```
   let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Json", ofType: "rtf")
    if let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfMappedFile: path!)
    {

        if let json: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as? NSDictionary
        {

        }
    }
```

NSData the i'm getting is neither getting converted as NSDictionary or NSArray. Please help me with the correct approach.

Comment: **In JSON**, `[` denotes the start of an *array*. JSON dictionaries start with `{`. Be careful to not confuse JSON syntax with Swift syntax for arrays and dictionaries, it's a common source of misunderstanding.

Comment: Why RTF? JSON is supposed to be plain text. The `NSData` object contains also all rich text formatting information which cannot be parsed by the (de)serializer.

Comment: Same as @EricD. Personnally, I always forget which one, so I just look for for the structure, looking for keys (dictionary) or just a "enumeration" (array)

Comment: @vadian Thank you.... Your response resolved my issue... Well rtf was the file we were using. I changed it to txt and it worked. I guess there was an issue due to the additional characters that cannot be parsed as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really, really, really need RTF you have to convert it to plain text for example

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Json", withExtension: "rtf")
if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: path!), attributedString = NSAttributedString(RTF: data, documentAttributes: nil) {
  let plainString = attributedString.string
  let jsonData = plainString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
  do {
     if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: []) as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
        // do something with json
     }
   } catch {
     print(error)
   }
}
```

but it's much easier to use plain text at once.

PS: In Swift it's always recommended to use Swift native collection types rather than the quite type unspecified Foundation classes `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

your response start at `Array` not at `dictionary`, in this place use

```
if let json: NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as? NSArray
    {

    }
}
```

**update**

```
 do {
 let json: NSArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as! NSArray
// use anyObj here
} catch {
print("json error: \(error)")
 }
```

for additional information see this [tutorial](http://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/10/how-to-parse-json-with-swift-2/)